# CasperJSの文字化け

Tags: casperjs

こちらの[**リンク**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227652/casperjs-parsing-page-with-non-utf8-encoding)に同じ質問がありますが、UTF8以外のサイトから情報取得しようとすると、文字化けが発生します。

サイトのタイトルは「"第28回いきいき大田写真コンクール作品募集"」の筈ですが、文字化けで「¥¨¥ì¥¯¥È¥í¥Ë¥¯¥¹」が出力されます。

```
/*=================================================*/
var casper = require("casper").create({
verbose: true,
logLevel: "debug"
});

function getMultiTextList(cssSelector) {
var query = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);
return Array.prototype.map.call(query, function (element) {
return element.innerText;
});
}

var testurl = "https://www.city.ota.tokyo.jp/";
var testcss = "#mainback > div.main.clearfix > div.main-c > div.oshirese.clearfix > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2) > a"
casper.start();

casper.thenOpen(testurl, function() {

this.save()
titleList = this.evaluate(getMultiTextList,testcss);

for (var i = 0; i < titleList.length; i++)
{
this.echo(titleList[i])
}
});

casper.run(function() {
this.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

UTF環境で実行したところ、文字化けは確認できませんでした。(casperjs 1.1.0-beta3, phantomjs 1.9.8)
ただ、`this.save()` は無かったので、削除して動かしました。
最初は下記のような最低限のコードでテストした方がよいかと思います。

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('https://www.city.ota.tokyo.jp/', function start(){
    this.echo(this.evaluate(function get_title(){
        return document.querySelector("title").text;
    }));
});
casper.run();
```